# StAX parser not moving forward when end tag not found

Tags: xml, parsing, stax

I am using StAX parser to read xml files. Some xml files are not well formatted, means some times end tags might be missing.
Example: 
       `<tag1>
           <tag2> </tag2>
           <tag3>
           <tag4> </tag4>
        </tag1>`
In this case StAX parser not moving forward when no end tag found. It is only reading up to 'tag3'.

Please suggest me how to solve this or any other parse which can parse the entire file irrespective of file format.

Comment: fixing xml to make them well formed before feeding to xml parsers... or write you own parsing procedure...  no easy way around this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input isn't "not well formatted XML", it isn't XML at all. You should provide a valid XML for an XML parser to work properly, irrespective of STaX or DOM.

Comment: Is there any framework to read such files ?. My main aim is to read the XML file tags and get the content irrespective of the format. I need to search for a tag if found read the content.

Comment: There are tools such as validator.nu and HTML Tidy that will attempt to create good XML out of rubbish XML. Far better, of course, is to avoid creating rubbish XML in the first place.

Comment: Creating XML file is not in my hands. Some other people create the files and I need to read them. That is why I am  looking for such tools.

Comment: You can use the tools mentioned by @MichaelKay or clean the input yourself (if you have knowledge of the process that creates the XML, you can simplify the problem by filtering unwanted data) if that is simpler.

Comment: @Rekha You don't need to accept shoddy goods from anyone. If it was software that didn't work, you would send it back. Why do you accept data that's equally broken?